# What happened to Count Dooku's lightsaber?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, lightsaber, revenge-of-the-sith

In *Star Wars: Episode III – Revenge of the Sith*, Dooku fights Kenobi and Anakin in front of the 'captured' Palpatine.  At the end of the duel, Anakin disarms (and dis-hands) Dooku and takes his lightsaber (and uses it, along with his own saber, to decapitate Dooku).  Anakin then 'pilots' the ship to Coruscant, presumably still in possession of Dooku's saber ...

What happens to Dooku's lightsaber after that?

Canon answers are preferred.  A 'best' answer will probably include both Canon and Legends answers.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Anakin left Dooku's lightsaber beside his corpse in General Grievous' quarters in the spire aboard the Invisible Hand.

[image]

This part of the ship was destroyed during their catastrophic landing (you can see it burning up in the atmosphere) and barring a miracle, the lightsaber was presumably also destroyed at the same time.

[image]

Comment: But why didn't Anakin take it? Don't Jedi knights pick up the lightsabers of the enemies they've defeated? For example, Obi-Wan picks up Anakin's after their duel. Should I ask it as a separate question?

Comment: @FabioTurati  I think that would make a great stand-alone question, yes.  But I'll speculate here that it might have something to do with the different natures of the two sabers.  Kenobi picked up the blue-bladed weapon of a Jedi.  Anakin rejected/refused/ignored(not sure the best word here) the red bladed weapon of a Sith.

Comment: @Dalila - For the record, there's no indication in the script or novelisations why he didn't keep it.

Comment: @Dalila Here it is: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/203513/82754

Comment: @FabioTurati - "Obi-Wan picks up Anakin's after their duel." That's because a movie made thirty years before hand required a plot coupon, that now in hindsight, no one ever wanted to see redeemed.

Comment: You mean the kind of miracle that might preserve Luke's lightsaber that fell down to Bespin?

Comment: @jpmc26 - Well, indeed.

Comment: @jpmc26 Coruscant's scavenger counterpart to Rey will no doubt find it in the wreck at some point, sell it on the black market to Maz, who will eventually turn it over to the one destined to become the next apprentice to Dooku ... wait ...

Comment: @Dalila Don't forget that the one destined to be Dooku's next apprentice needs to become completely indifferent, and toss Dooku's "laser sword" behind him.

Comment: @jpmc26 - hey. you seen a hand come down here?